# Minimized windows disappear

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, taskbar

Working on a RPi3B+, latest raspbian version. Everything working well until I noticed that any window that was minimized no longer showed up on the top taskbar. Looked at taskbar options (very limited), tried some out and was not able to make the minimized tabs reappear.

I do understand that alt-tab will allow me to get/flip through the windows that have been minimized, but something is broken and I would like some help to understand what it is and how to fix it.

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: If I read the question in a year, what would be the latest raspbian version?

Comment: Kernel version 4.19, May 2020.

Comment: The kernel version isn't the version of the operating system? Do you use version Buster?

Comment: output from cat /etc/os-release --> Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Comment: Same result with the Buster release of March, 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Panel Preferences -> Panel Applets -> Add Task Bar (Window List)

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to remove a spacer from the panel

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/129807)